# The Rule Execution Server component of IBM Decision Server doesn't seem to be installed

Tags: ibm-odm

I am new to the IBM Rule Designer.
I have created some rules with Eclipse Rule Designer, in order to test I want to use a local execution server, when I try to create a test case through **DVS Decision Operation** I get the following error:

**The Rule Execution Server component of IBM Decision Server doesn't seem to be installed. The default classpath might be incorrect and have missing files.**

Can anyone please assist on this?

Execution server version: 8.8

Comment: Hi Federico, If you found the resolution please share here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do 2 things to run your rules.

1. Get a RES running on your machine, or elsewhere.  If you are on windows, the simplest path is to start the sample server from the start menu or by running the [odm install dir]\bin\startserver.bat script.

This will start a sample server at the following url:
http://localhost:9090/res/
login with resAdmin:resAdmin

2. Point your Rule Designer toward this RES server.  Do this by navigating to the "Rule Execution Servers" pane in the bottom center of RD.  Hit the icon with the server computer and a '+'.  Then use the url and credentials above to create the connection.